# How to store mySQL query result into pandas DataFrame with pymysql?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, pymysql

I'm trying to store a mySQL query result in a pandas DataFrame using `pymysql` and am running into errors building the dataframe. Found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43151779/exporting-sql-query-results-to-pandas-dataframe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047193/how-to-convert-sql-query-result-to-pandas-data-structure), but it looks like there are `pymysql`-specific errors being thrown:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import pymysql

# dummy values 
connection = pymysql.connect(user='username', password='password', databse='database_name', host='host')

start_date = datetime.datetime(2017,11,15)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2017,11,16)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    query = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE date_time BETWEEN %s AND %s"

    cursor.execute(query, (start_date, end_date)) 

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=cursor.fetchall(), index = None, columns = cursor.keys())
finally:
    connection.close()
```

returns: `AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'keys'`

If I drop the `index` and `columns` arguments:

```
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    query = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE date_time BETWEEN %s AND %s"

    cursor.execute(query, (start_date, end_date)) 

    df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
finally:
    connection.close()
```

returns `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use [Pandas.read_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) for this:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE date_time BETWEEN ? AND ?"
df = pd.read_sql(query, connection,  params=(start_date, end_date))
```

Comment: pandas.read_sql() works well in general. However, what if the command is to execute a stored procedure which needs to update a table (and commit the updated rows of the table)? In that case, how to ensure the commit is done? Does pd.read_sql allow commits?

Comment: @Nodame, you can first call your stored procedure using sqlalchemy and then read results using pd.read_sql

Comment: How does a pymysql conmection work with pandas read_sql since pymysql Connection doesnt inherit from any schlalchemy class?

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql

mysql_connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', db='test', charset='utf8')
                    
sql = "SELECT * FROM `brands`"
df = pd.read_sql(sql, mysql_connection, index_col='brand_id')
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your suggestion to use pandas.read_sql().  It works with executing a stored procedure as well!  I tested it in MSSQL 2017 environment.

Below is an example (I hope it helps others):

```
def database_query_to_df(connection, stored_proc, start_date, end_date):
    # Define a query
    query ="SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC " + stored_proc + " ?, ? " + "; SET NOCOUNT OFF"

    # Pass the parameters to the query, execute it, and store the results in a data frame
    df = pd.read_sql(query, connection, params=(start_date, end_date))
    return df
```